# How to efficiently calculate a function on a vector of variants?

Tags: c++, vector, c++17, variant

I have a vector of variants that can store either uint64_t and double types, and I want to calculate the median over them.

At any given time, the vector is composed entirely of uint64_t's or double's

The solution I have so far as outlined below works but it seems redundant in terms of code, and I want to know if there is a better way to achieve this result.

```
typedef std::variant<uint64_t, double> data_variant;

data_variant calculate_median(const std::vector<data_variant>& data) {
    auto index = data.back().index();

    // uint64_t
    if (index == 0) {
      std::vector<uint64_t> vec;
      for (auto& i: data) {
        vec.emplace_back(std::get<uint64_t>(i));
      }

      const auto median_it = vec.begin() + vec.size() / 2;
      std::nth_element(vec.begin(), median_it , vec.end());
      return *median_it;
    // double
    } else if (index == 1) {
      std::vector<double> vec;
      for (auto& i: data) {
        vec.emplace_back(std::get<double>(i));
      }

      const auto median_it = vec.begin() + vec.size() / 2;
      std::nth_element(vec.begin(), median_it , vec.end());
      return *median_it;
    }
  }
```

Comment: There's a lot of duplicated code there, to me, that suggests a function template to handle it.  You would parameterize it with `double` or `uint64_t`.  That, or push the strong typing upstream via templates, so you don't have a vector of variants but instead a vector of whatever the right type is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in the duplicated code is a type, so you can factor out a function template like this:

```
template<typename T>
data_variant calculate_median_impl(const std::vector<data_variant>& data) 
{
      std::vector<T> vec;
      for (auto& i: data) 
      {
        vec.emplace_back(std::get<T>(i));
      }

      const auto median_it = vec.begin() + vec.size() / 2;
      std::nth_element(vec.begin(), median_it , vec.end());
      return *median_it;
}
```

and then select which one to call separately:

```
data_variant calculate_median(const std::vector<data_variant>& data) 
{
    return data.back().index() 
           ? calculate_median_impl<uint64_t>(data)
           : calculate_median_impl<double>(data);     
}
```

Comment: So there's no way to calculate_median_impl to automatically determine the type of variant being passed in?

Comment: @SyedJafri - No. The type inside the variant is know run-time, the type of `vec` (so the `T` type) has to be decided compile-time. You need to pass the type as a template parameter because the template parameter is known compile time. This force you to insert two distinct calls to `calculate_median_impl()` inside `calculate_median()` because, run-time, you can decide which function call but you can't decide, run-time, which type pass, as template parameter, to the function.

Answer (score 1):

In term of simplification of code, you can receive the `data` by copy and simply

```
data_variant calculate_median (std::vector<data_variant> data)
 {
   auto const median_it = data.begin() + (data.size() >> 1u);

   std::nth_element(data.begin(), median_it, data.end());

   return *median_it;
 }
```

But, maybe, this loose efficiency.